# how to write soapclient function in php?

Tags: php

I want to know that how to write following soap request in PHP using soapclient function ?

---

WSDL : https://test.edentiti.com/Registrations-Registrations/DynamicFormsService?wsdl

Action to call :

```
    > <soapenv:Envelope
    > xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    > xmlns:dyn="http://dynamicform.services.registrations.edentiti.com/">  
    > <soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
    >       <dyn:registerVerification>
    >          <accountId>ABCDEFGHIJKL</accountId>
    >          <password>1010101010</password>
    >          <ruleId>default</ruleId>
    >          <name>
    >             <givenName>John</givenName>
    >             <honorific></honorific>
    >             <middleNames></middleNames>
    >             <surname>Citizen</surname>
    >          </name>
    >          <email>john@edentiti.com</email>
    >          <currentResidentialAddress>
    >             <country>AUS</country>
    >             <postcode>2000</postcode>
    >             <state>NSW</state>
    >             <streetName>address</streetName>
    >             <streetNumber></streetNumber>
    >             <streetType></streetType>
    >             <suburb>city</suburb>
    >          </currentResidentialAddress>
    >  
    >          <generateVerificationToken>false</generateVerificationToken>
    >       </dyn:registerVerification>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

I want to know that how to write above in following function.

```
//Create the client object
$soapclient = new SoapClient('');
$params = array(...........);
$response = $soapclient->.......($params);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: try using NuSOAP PHP library

Comment: @PravinS Why should he use a 3rd-party lib when he asks for the native client? What's wrong with the native soap client?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have been using it for a while and had a good experience, so just a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the `registerVerification` method with an array of data as the only parameter:

```
$wsdl = 'https://test.edentiti.com/Registrations-Registrations/DynamicFormsService?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$registerVerificationData = [
    'accountId' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKL',
    'password' => '1010101010',
    'ruleId' => 'default',
    'name' => [
        'givenName' => 'John',
        'honorific' => null,
        'middleNames' => null,
        'surname' => 'Citizen',
    ],
    'email' => 'john@edentiti.com',
    'currentResidentialAddress' => [
        'country' => 'AUS',
        'postcode' => '2000',
        'state' => 'NSW',
        'streetName' => null,
        'streetNumber' => null,
        'streetType' => null,
        'suburb' => 'city',
    ],
    'generateVerificationToken' => false,
];
$response = $client->registerVerification($registerVerificationData);
var_dump($response);
```

If the SOAP server requires the `null` properties to be defined, you can replace all the `null` values with `SoapVar` instances before calling `registerVerification()`:

```
array_walk_recursive($registerVerificationData, function (&$value) {
    if ($value === null) {
        $value = new SoapVar(null, XSD_ANYTYPE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi pieter. can you give answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810785/how-to-write-array-of-soap-api-call  ?   I just confuse in write php array.